# Mongo DB and saving very long data

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am using sailsjs as framework and I want to save this json response to my mongo db. https://gist.github.com/FiatPax/b531d9cfd38f2615c580fe8ef26a4fa0

I receive this error

> MongoError: Regular expression is too long

The code I am using to save is

```
var str = JSON.stringify(response.body)
ItemPrices.findOrCreate({ appid: 440, itemprices: str }).exec(function createFindCB(error, createdOrFoundRecords) {
                            console.log(createdOrFoundRecords);
                            console.log(error);
                        });
```

In case you wanna know what findOrCreate does: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/master/lib/waterline/query/composite.js#L24

**How do I hold this very long data in mongo db from a received response?**

Comment: If the JSON string is larger than 16 MB, MongoDB won't save it. It's an arbitrary limit. Your only two options are to split the string into smaller parts in the DB or do some extreme string compression (and that might not work if the string is too long)

Comment: Then it should save it without issue. The arbitrary limit is 16 MB for strings. https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Not if it's trying to match a 1mb string. Use a hash to identify the content.